# how to handle transaction in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a simple post API using django rest framework. 
The request data is

```
{
    "name":"Sweetd Cakeq",
    "protein":"oh1.0",
    "carb":1.0,
    "fat":1.0
}
```

so i am saving Product and Ingredients. now i expect Product and Ingredients to be on the same transaction. Products and Ingredients should either be totally saved or both should be rolled back.

The code written in the view is somehow working but i'm not sure if it is the right approach. can someone verify if i'm doing it right or not?

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ingredients")
    protein = models.FloatField()
    carb = models.FloatField()
    fat = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**Views.py**

```
class GlobalApiResponse():

    def error_response(self, response, status):
        print(response)
        return Response({"error": response, "status": status})

    def success_response(self, data, status):
        return Response({"message": "posted successfully", "data": data, "status": status})


class ProductView(APIView, GlobalApiResponse):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                product = serializer.save()
                request.data['product'] = product.pk
                ing_ser = IngridientSerializer(data=request.data)
                if ing_ser.is_valid():
                    ing_ser.save()
                    return self.success_response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                else:
                    transaction.set_rollback(True)
                    return self.error_response(response=ing_ser.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return self.error_response(response=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can update view like this.

```
class ProductView(APIView, GlobalApiResponse):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ing_ser = IngridientSerializer(data=request.data)
        ing_ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                product = serializer.save()
                ing_ser.save(product=product)
                return self.success_response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except IntegrityError:
            handle_exception()
```

Django transactions [atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic):

> If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.

Handle exception, [IntegrityError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)

> Note that any operations attempted in atomic block will already have been rolled back safely when handle_exception() is called, so the exception handler can also operate on the database if necessary.